# How do I set CBAUTH_REVRPC_URL in Couchbase N1QL?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Working with 4.0.
I ran "./cbq-engine -datastore=http://localhost:8091".
First message in the log is:
"level=ERROR msg= Unable to initialize cbauth. Error Unable to initialize cbauth's revrpc: cbauth environment variable CBAUTHREVRPC_URL is not set ".
And indeed when I try to run CREATE PRIMARY INDEX I get an error:
"Indexer not implemented GSI may not be enabled"

Answer (score 0):

You should install Couchbase 4.0 and run it directly. After that, you can run cbq (not cbq-engine) as above.

You should not run cbq-engine manually.

Comment: Sorry, but today I've downloaded Couchbase 4.0, and the cbq-engine service it is not running by default (I have to do it manually).

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to solve this issue you have to set a new environment variable, by doing (before calling cbq-engine)

```
export CBAUTH_REVRPC_URL="http://User:Pass@localhost:8091/query"
```

Hope this works!